# How to combine FILTER and UNIQUE in Google Sheets, but to show all unique cells, instead of all unique rows/columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So, I'm using Google Sheets to study UK railway timetables to try and work out how many unique stations are served by trains from a particular railway station. The example I'm showing is of my analysis of London Euston station. It is laid out as follows:[image: A spreadsheet showing a list of removed services in the top left corner, a counter for number of unique stations served on the left, currently showing 45, and then in each column progressing right-wards the stations served by each train leaving the station] However, I'm now trying to filter this spreadsheet so I can get a concise list of the 45 counted unique stations, but I believe the =UNIQUE function works in rows or columns rather than the desired cells. I have already researching how to do it, but Google isn't being very helpful and is always leading me down the =UNIQUE pathway. Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do in Google Sheets?

Screenshotted below is my latest attempt, following yet another tutorial from Google, and yet again running into the "Would overwrite data in another cell" error from Google Sheets.[image: =UNIQUE(B3:AF30,TRUE,FALSE) leading to an error message about overwriting data in another cell.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=unique(tocol(B3:AF30,1))
```